# Django DetailView: related objects

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset, detailview

Got 4 Models:

**models.py**

```
class Buildings(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Zones(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Departments(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    zone = models.ForeignKey(Zones, related_name='departments')

class Rooms(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Departments, related_name='rooms')
    building = models.ForeignKey(Buildings, related_name='buildings')
```

What I'm trying to do is:

Create DetailView of a Buildings in which we see:

- departments inside the building
- rooms inside the building
- zones each room belongs to

Now in **views.py** I have:

```
class BuildingsDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Buildings

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BuildingsDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['Rooms'] = Rooms.objects.filter(building=self.get_object())
        context['Zones'] = Zones.objects.filter(departments__rooms__buildings=self.get_object())
        return context
```

**detail.html**
In DetailView I can now access Rooms, Departments and Zones but I'cant match Zones to Rooms. It prints buildings and rooms with departments correctly, then multiplies it with all Zones in building.

```
{% for rm in Rooms %}
    {% for zn in Zones %}
        <p> {{ rm.name }} </p>
        <p> {{ rm.department }} </p>
        <p> {{ zn.name }} </p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Output:

```
Room 1
Depart A
Zone 1

Room 1
Depart A
Zone 2
```

etc.

**How can I match Zone name to corresponding Department of each Room in a Building correctly?**
Room and Depart name is matched correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping over separate querysets which won't match up, just access the related models from the instance you have. Try this in the template:

```
{% for rm in Rooms %}
    <p> {{ rm.name }} </p>
    <p> {{ rm.department }} </p>
    <p> {{ rm.department.zone.name }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```